# C# - unable to process enter and tab key event

Tags: c#, winforms

I am new c#, I am using below code, but the code is not working for Enter key and the Tab key. Please Solve this problem…

```
private void Panel_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(C_event);
}

private void C_event(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        Label1.Text = "Enter Key";
        return;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == Keys.Tab)
    {
        Label1.text = "Tab Key";
        return;
    }

    label1.text = "Default";
}
```

Comment: Only as a hint, try other kind of events, maybe something like KeyPressed do the job.

Comment: Please have a look at SO link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10641721/c-sharp-unable-to-capture-enter-key?rq=1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3752451/enter-key-pressed-event-handler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be able to handle Enter/Tab key presses you should override the ProcessCmdKey method

```
 protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        if (!this.ProcessKey(msg, keyData))
        {
            return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
        }
        return false;
    }

    protected virtual bool ProcessKey(Message msg,Keys keyData)
    {
        //The condition needs to be either `if ((keyData & Keys.Enter) == keyData)` or `if (keyData == Keys.Enter)`.
        if ((keyData & Keys.Enter) == Keys.Enter)
        {
            Label1.Text = "Enter Key";
            return true;
        }
        if ((keyData & Keys.Tab) == Keys.Tab)
        {
            Label1.Text = "Tab Key";
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

MSDN [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown(v=vs.110).aspx) is pretty clear on this:

> Certain keys, such as the **TAB**, **RETURN**, ESC, and arrow keys are handled by controls automatically.
>
> To have these keys raise the KeyDown event, you must override the [`IsInputKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.previewkeydowneventargs.isinputkey(v=vs.110).aspx) method in each control on your form.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `KeyPreview` property of your `Form` to `True`.

Try This:

```
private void Panel_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.KeyPreview= true; //add this line
    this.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(C_event);
}
```

Comment: While it's true, [you shouldn't use `KeyPreview` though](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386695/disadvantage-of-setting-form-keypreview-true).

Answer (score -2):

```
// Structure contain information about low-level keyboard input event
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT
    {
        public Keys key;
        public int scanCode;
        public int flags;
        public int time;
        public IntPtr extra;
    }

    //System level functions to be used for hook and unhook keyboard input
    private delegate IntPtr LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int id, LowLevelKeyboardProc callback, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hook);
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hook, int nCode, IntPtr wp, IntPtr lp);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string name);
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern short GetAsyncKeyState(Keys key);

    //Declaring Global objects
    private IntPtr ptrHook;
    private LowLevelKeyboardProc objKeyboardProcess;

    private IntPtr CaptureKey(int nCode, IntPtr wp, IntPtr lp)
    {
        if (nCode >= 0)
        {
            KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT objKeyInfo = (KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lp, typeof(KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT));
            if (objKeyInfo.key == Keys.Tab || objKeyInfo.key == Keys.Enter) // Disabling Windows keys
            {
                MessageBox.Show("TAB or Enter  PRESSED");
                return (IntPtr)1;
            }

        }
        return CallNextHookEx(ptrHook, nCode, wp, lp);
    }
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        //Get Current Module
        ProcessModule objCurrentModule = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule;
        //Assign callback function each time keyboard process
        objKeyboardProcess = new LowLevelKeyboardProc(CaptureKey);
        //Setting Hook of Keyboard Process for current module
        ptrHook = SetWindowsHookEx(13, objKeyboardProcess, GetModuleHandle(objCurrentModule.ModuleName), 0);
    }
```

Comment: Just dumping some code isn't an answer, and a keyboard hook is a particularly bad way to solve this problem, so -1.